# Bazaar merge hook?

Tags: bazaar

i want to run a batch file after a merge operation to resolve certain conflicts automatically.

any ideas?

post_merge_hook will work just fine but i didnt find any references for it existence

thanks

Gil Idelson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no post-merge hook in Bazaar. Your best bet is to make a shell alias or batch file which executes the merge and then your conflict resolution tool.

Another alternative is to create a plugin which registers a [merge_file_content hook](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/user-reference/hooks-help.html#merge-file-content) that controls how bzr merges specific files. Since bzr 2.4, there is bundled plugin called news_merge which demonstrates how this can be used. You may also want to read about [hooks in the user guide](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/user-guide/hooks.html).

Unless the standard merge algorithms really cannot handle your special files correctly, I would recommend the first option.